# Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect string value

Tags: mysql, pdo, mariadb

This is the error I am getting.

> PDOException: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x98\xB3' for column 'string' at row 1'

I know the problem here. The column table is using `utf8`. The `utf8` encoding cannot store 4 byte characters so it errors. A way to get around this could be to use `utf8mb4` instead.

My question instead is about the error message. We are using MariaDB. **Why does it say "Invalid datetime format" in the error message?** This is a text field. There is nothing to do with datetime in the query being run.

This "Invalid datetime format" comes up often for a variety of errors but seems unrelated to the actual source of the error.

Comment: because a mysql date/time string is `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`. Given your `\xF0`, you're passing something not even remotely CLOSE to that form. And since you  haven't shown your actual query, we can't do anything to help you.

Comment: What Marc B. said. Don't send an `utf8` encoded string as a `datetime` parameter, that's all.

Comment: If you're positively sure that no dates have been harmed in the execution of this query, it might be you've hit some of those strange bugs that make our lives more interesting. How reproducible is it? Could you provide a self-contained example?

Comment: Let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the SQL directly involved in the error message.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I've seen this before.

I suppose it's a bug on the mariadb side, where all errors on the incorrect values are dubbed as "incorrect datetime value".

I see no harm here though beside a little confusion. Just keep in mind the issue and treat it as "incorrect text value"